# Should I use std::move when moving local variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the below code:

```
Bar my_f()
{
    Foo f{args,to,create,foo};
    Bar b{std::move(f),other,args}; //Is move here unnecessary?

    // code that does not use f;

    return b;
}
```

Is compiler required to check `{code that does not use f}` and automatically move `f` into `b`?

Comment: It is very unlikely the compiler will move `f`. It may do something more efficient and easy to implement, as long as it follows the as-if rule. There's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the compiler would do that...I doubt a compiler would do that automatically because it would break scoping rules.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler will not automatically move the object into the constructor of `Bar`, just because `f` is not used afterwards. If you want to move `f`, either make it explicit with `std::move(f)` or remove the named variable:

```
Bar b{Foo{args, to, create, foo}, other, args}; // will automatically move (if possible)
```